# How can I get the second index within a nested for loop to work in a data table

Tags: r, loops, data.table, increment

So I have a `data.table` where I need to fill in values based on the index of the column and then also based on the placeholder character. Example:

```
       V1   V2   V3    V4
Row1   1    1    a     d     
Row2   1    1    a     d
Row3   1    1    a     d
Row4   1    2    a     h
Row5   1    2    a     h
Row6   1    2    a     h
Row7   2    1    b     i
Row8   2    1    b     i
Row9   2    1    b     i
Row10  2    2    b     t
Row11  2    2    b     t
Row12  2    2    b     t

....
Row350k   ...
```

What I need to figure out is how to write a `for` loop with a assignment by reference statement that slides along column 1's index. Basically

For each column index, one at a time:

- For each `V1 = 1` and `V2 = 1` replace character 'a' with one
  iteration of  0.0055 + rnorm(1, 0.0055, 0.08).
- For each `V1 = 1` and
  `V2 = 2` replace character 'a' with one iteration of  0.0055 +
  rnorm(1, 0.0055, 0.08). (same variation but with another iteration of
  the rnorm)
- For each `V1 = 2` and `V1 = 1`, replace character 'b' with
  one iteration of 0.0055 + rnorm(1, 0.001, 0.01)
- For each `V1 = 2` and
  `V1 = 1`, replace character 'b' with one iteration of 0.0055 +
  rnorm(1, 0.001, 0.01) (same variation but with another iteration of
  the rnorm).

And so on for each incrementing values of Col1 and Col2. In actuality its 20+ rows instead of just 2 for the second index.

Desired output then is:

```
    Col1  Col2   Col3     Col4
Row1   1    1    0.00551    d     
Row2   1    1    0.00551    d
Row3   1    1    0.00551    d
Row4   1    2    0.00553    h
Row5   1    2    0.00553    h
Row6   1    2    0.00555    h
Row7   2    1    0.0011     i
Row8   2    1    0.0011     i
Row9   2    1    0.0011     i
Row10  2    2    0.0010     t
Row11  2    2    0.0010     t
Row12  2    2    0.0010     t
....
Row350k   ...
```

Just not sure how to do this with a loop since the values in col1 are repeated a certain num of times. **Column1 has 300k plus values so the sliding loop needs to dynamically scalable.**

Here's what i have tried:

```
for (i in seq(1, 4000, 1)) 
{for (ii in seq(1, 2, 1)) {
    data.table[V3 == "a" , V3 := 0.0055 + rnorm(1, 0.0055, 0.08)]
    data.table[V3 == "b" , V3 := 0.0055 + rnorm(1, 0.001, 0.01)]
    }}
```

Thanks!

Comment: By your description it seems that the results depend on V1, however you use V3 in your example. Is V3 = ifelse(V1 ==1, "a", "b")

Comment: Sorry, its supposed to be V3 not V55. I'm replacing the value in V3 of a or b with a number.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use V3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out that I wasn't incrementing my counters properly. For a matrix/data table with 4000 scenarios in the 1st column each with 11 repeats in the 2nd column I used the follwing:

```
 Col1counter <- 1
 Col2counter <- 1

for(Col1counter in 1:4000) {

  for(col2counter in 1:11) {

     test1[V1 == col1counter & V2 == col2counter &  V3 == "a" ,  V55 := 0.00558 + rnorm(1, 0.00558, 2)]

  col2counter+ 1
    }
Col1counter+ 1}
```

Using both indices in the conditional statement ensures that it crawls accurately through the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly this might be of help.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(V1 = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6)), 
                 V2 = rep(c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)), 2),
                 V3 = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6)),
                 V4 = c(rep("d", 3), rep("h", 3), rep("i", 3), rep("t", 3)))

# define a catalog to join on V3 which contains the parameters for the random number generation
catalog <- data.table(V3 = c("a", "b"),
                      const = 0.0055,
                      mean = c(0.0055, 0.001),
                      std = c(0.08, 0.01))

# for each value of V3 generate .N (number of observations of the current V3 value) random numbers with the specified parameters
dt[catalog, V5 := i.const + rnorm(.N, i.mean, i.std), on = "V3", by = .EACHI]
dt[, V3 := V5]
dt[, V5 := NULL]
```